# Array.filter with asynchronous issue

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I'm getting a data set by calling API side asynchronously. But my my client method returning observable.
So I converted it to promise and returning my values.

```
 const statusTypes = ['paid','default','open'];
    const data: any = await this.reportService.getReport(payload).toPromise()
    const invoices = await this.getFilteredDataByStatusArray(data.invoices, statusTypes );
    const tempSelectedStaus = [...statusTypes ];
    const withoutOverdueStatus: any = await this.getNotOverdueList(tempSelectedStaus);
//some code here
```

so here is the getNotOverdueList method inside code,

```
async getNotOverdueList(arrayData) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        return resolve(arrayData.filter(s => s !== 'Overdue'));
      } catch (err) {
        this.logger.error(err);
        return [];
      }

    });
  }
```

After that there are few code lines in my code, but those lines are not executing when executing this method getNotOverdueList. it's returning after this method execute.

Do you have any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix the async version and promise version together in one function writing.

The promise version is a function returning a promise driven by `resolve` and `reject`.

```
function getNotOverdueList(arrayData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return resolve(arrayData.filter(s => s !== 'Overdue'));
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(err);
      return resolve([]);   // or reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

The async version is a function returning a value by driven by `return` and `throw`.

```
async function getNotOverdueList(arrayData) {
  try {
    return arrayData.filter(s => s !== 'Overdue');
  } catch (err) {
    this.logger.error(err);
    return []   // or throw err
  }
}
```

Both version can be called via `getNotOverdueList(...).then(res)`. When inside an `async` function, the async version can be called with `await getNotOverdueList(...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But still having same issue. In your code,
filter function is a synchronized one right? so if we convert getNotOverdueList as async one, is useless I think.

Comment: If `filter` is async, then do `return await arrayData.filter(...)` in the async version.

Comment: It's saying 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression
after adding await